# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. memory leak in my function

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnhX8.png)

Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
everytime i navigate to another route this is the waring i get. how to solve this?
[this a portion of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wez0B.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you provide more code, please? Because it doesn't look like that portion of the code has any problems.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.